# Substringing JSON keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a form with inputs using this naming convetion:

```
  <input class="xxlarge" name="note[url]" id="url" placeholder="URL">
```

So, I'm using [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/serialize-form-to-json-with-jquery) (found on StackOverflow) that serializes form data into JSON.

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
var o = {};
var a = this.serializeArray();
$.each(a, function() {
    if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
        if (!o[this.name].push) {
            o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
        }
        o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
    } else {
        o[this.name] = this.value || '';
    }
});
return o;
};
```

and on the output I have this:

```
  {"note[url]":"URL","note[title]":"TITLE"}
```

I'd like to know how to transform this script to get output like this:

```
  {"url":"URL","title":"TITLE"}
```

I'm handling this from with rather standard, documented code block (using function, described above):

```
      $(function() {
      $('form').submit(function() {
        $('#result').html(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
          $.post(
              "/api/create",
              JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()),
              function(responseText){
                  $("#result").html(responseText);
              },
              "html"
          );
          return false;
      });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think a little more of your code would be helpful here.

Comment: Given that field name notation, are you using a PHP server? Any reason you need to split those values up in JS? PHP will happily convert them to an array for you once the data's submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest parsing the string into a JS object, changing the keys in a for loop, then stringifying it when you're done.  Like so:

```
// turn the string into a JS object
var data = JSON.parse('{"note[url]":"URL","note[title]":"TITLE"}');
var newData = {};
// step through each member
for(key in data) {
  // Regular expressions to find the brackets
  var newKeyStart = key.search(/note\[/) + 5;
  var newKeyEnd = key.search(/\]/);
  // pull out the desired part of the key
  var newKey = key.substr(newKeyStart,  newKeyEnd - newKeyStart);
  // insert into new data object
  newData[newKey] = data[key];
  }
// turn back into JSON again
var newJSON = JSON.stringify(newData);
```

Comment: Not that you can't depend on the JSON library to be present on older browsers.  If you're concerned about that, include Douglas Crockford's JSON library: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where your 'note' part is coming from. May be something you could fix via the `name` attributes in your markup. Otherwise you could always do something like:

```
function renameKeys(obj) {
    var 
        result = {},
        key,
        check,
        noteReg = /^note\[([^\]]+)\]$/;

    for(key in obj) {
        result[(check = key.match(noteReg)) === null ? key : check[1]] = typeof obj[key] == 'object' && toString.call(obj[key]) == '[object Object]' ? renameKeys(obj[key]) : obj[key];
    }

    return result;
}
```

which can be used to make a *new* object with the keys you want.

```
renameKeys({"note[url]":"URL","note[title]":"TITLE"}); 
// { url: 'URL', title: 'TITLE' }

renameKeys({"note[url]":"URL","note[title]":"TITLE", anotherObj: { thingA: 1234, 'note[thingB]': 9492}});
// { url: 'URL', title: 'TITLE', anotherObj: { thingA: 1234, thingB: 9492 } }
```

Beware, though, that if you have something like a key of `note[asdf]` *and* a key of `asdf` then whichever is iterated over last will overwrite the other.